# very basic ruby/sinatra/heroku/debugging question: how to see output of puts and p?

Tags: ruby, debugging, heroku, sinatra

I'm trying to build a very simple sinatra app deployed on heroku.

our app is not outputting stuff to a web browser, it's communicating with another computer via an API. so my usual trick of just printing a little extra debugging info to the browser while I'm using the app doesnt work.

the sample code I've seen for related apps show multiple 'puts' or 'p' statement used ot sort of see what's going on...

where does the output go that I can see that output as the program executes, or afterwards.

and in general, if you're flailing around with code hosted at Heroku that's just not doing what you want, what IS the easiest way to at various places in the code output messages like "foo equals 123" so you can see that output to figure out what's happening in the code?

p and puts dont output so the logs I can see when I type "heroku logs" for example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://docs.heroku.com/logging you should be able to have `puts` and `p` just go to your log if you add the basic logger (which has apparently been added by default to all apps created after February 2nd, 2011).

For non-Heroku basic log-to-file with Sinatra and Logger:

```
require 'logger'
Dir.mkdir('logs') unless File.exist?('logs')
$log = Logger.new('logs/output.log','weekly')

configure :production do
  $log.level = Logger::WARN
end
configure :development do
  $log.level = Logger::DEBUG
end

get "/" do
  $log.debug "Hello, World!"
end
```

Comment: if I add the logger (which is for rails, i'm using sinatra) and then type "heroku logs" the heroku command fails: This feature is not supported by your client version. and the approach of writing to a localo file will not work on heroku far as I know...

Comment: Logger is not "for Rails", it is [part of the Standard Library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/index.html). I use it in all of my Sinatra apps. However, you are probably correct that Heroku doesn't support local files, which makes that portion of my answer useless to you. The second part of my answer seems to be exactly what you need, however, right?

Comment: Heroku's system does not allow writing of log files.

Comment: @DaveSag I'll edit my answer to move the relevant link and message to the top for more clarity.

Answer (score 10):

If you use a cedar stack, try to put a line bellow in config.ru,

```
$stdout.sync = true
```

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby#logging

Original post was in February 2011, and Cedar stack was introduced in May, so this doesn't seem to be help for original question, but some of you may find this could be help.
http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/5/31/celadon_cedar/

Answer (score 3):

This will work fine.  `test_logging.rb`

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'logger'

enable :logging

before do
  logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
end

get '/' do
  logger.debug "Handling 'hello world' request."
  logger.info "Hello world."

  return "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

See here for tips on how to write to the Logger: http://mikenaberezny.com/2007/02/24/rails-logging-tips/

The example given is:

```
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    logger.info 'informational message'
  end
end
```

Comment: correct, I tried logger.info and it throws an error in the heroku logs NameError - undefined local variable or method `logger' for #<Sinatra::Application:

Answer (score 0):

This is the line that works for me:

```
# On config.ru, before run:
enable :logging, :dump_errors, :raise_errors
```